# How to use iMac (27-inch, Late 2013) as a second monitor for Macbook Pro (13-inch, 2020)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac, thunderbolt, target-display

I bought Thunderbolt 3 (USB-c) to Thunderbolt 2 by Apple and Thunderbolt Cable (0,5m). Cmd+F2 doesn't work for me. I guess it's just because Apple now prevents to use old iMacs as monitor with new Macbooks. So my question mainly is there any other non-conventional way to use my iMac as a monitor with my new Macbook?
What if I run Windows in my old iMac? Would it be easier to connect it as a monitor to new Macbook?

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/335392/237687

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this thread doesn't really answer my question or anyone's really.